# Infinite linear span vs closed linear span

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, ds.dynamical-systems, cohomology

Hi,

Suppose we have a (real, separable) Banach space $V$ and a (linear) set $A\subseteq V$.  I presume in general it might not be possible to write every element of the closed span of $A$ as an infinite linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\beta_i a_i$ of elements of $A$.  Are there simple (non-trivial) conditions guaranteeing that the closed linear span of $A$ coincides with its infinite linear span (perhaps with unconditional/absolute convergence)?

My example of interest is the following:  Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $F:X\to X$ a continuous map.  My space $V$ is the space $C(X)$ of continuous (real-valued) functions on $X$, and $A$ is the subset of functions that can be written as $\varphi\circ F - \varphi$ for some $\varphi\in C(X)$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Just to clarify: we can define linear subspaces $A_u$ and $A_a$ where the former consists of all unconditionally convergent sums of things in $A$, and the latter consists of all absolutely convergent sums of things in $A$, and you are asking under what "reasonable" conditions $A_u=A$ or $A_a=A$?

Comment: The question was under what reasonable conditions $A_u$ or $A_a$ is the same as the closure of the linear span of $A$.  But in case $A$ is a linear subspace itself (which was my primary interest), the answer is trivial as Wolfgang pointed out.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of linear $A$, which seems to be your case of interest, you can simply do it as follows. For $x$ in the closure of $A$ take a sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ converging to $x$ such that $\|x_n-x_{n+1}\|<2^{-n}$. Then set $a_i=x_i-x_{i-1}$, $\beta_i=1$ and the sum will converge absolutely, hence also unconditionally to $x$. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Oh well... You are right.  What was I thinking!  I ill-posed my problem, but your answer made things clearer in my mind.  Thank you very much.